# writeData() to second sheet without overwriting first sheet

Tags: r, openxlsx

If i have an excel file called my_table.xlsx which has one sheet containing some data. Is there then a way to add a second sheet with some data without overwriting what's in sheet one?

For example this code will remove the data that already exists in sheet 1.

```
wb <- createWorkbook()

addWorksheet(wb, sheet = 1)
addWorksheet(wb, sheet = 2)

writeData(wb, 2, "test")

saveWorkbook(wb, file = "my_table.xlsx", overwrite = 
TRUE)
```

Comment: I would look into using write.xlsx2 or write_xlsx for this. For write.xlsx2 there is an `append` argument.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately i'm unable to use the xlsx package at work due to the java dependency.

Comment: Ahh encountered a similar problem myself hence the swap to write_xlsx. It lets you write multiple sheets in one line and no java dependency.